# Run a .dmg file through java code

Tags: java, macos

How can I mount a .dmg file through java code under OS X?

Comment: From a security standpoint, there are several things in the way of 'running' a .dmg file in OS X.  It's a protected class of action that involves a regulated UI in order to assure users of certain securities in the OS.  Unless you are hacking, you should reconsider your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), of course.  But it won't work anywhere except on a Mac.

Comment: I used this code.It didn't run. Even didn't throw error.      String cmd = ("Users/acr/Desktop/dabkrl.dmg");
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
ProcessBuilder p = new  ProcessBuilder(new  String[] { "/usr/bin/open",
cmd });
Process pro;
try  {
pro = p.start();
InputStream is = pro.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new  InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new  BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
while  ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
}

Comment: I changed the ProcesBuilder. It works like a charm.      ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"open", cmd});

Comment: IMHO you should NOT use "open" to run a .dmg file, since this will fail on a system with corrupted MIME-types. If you use hdutil (the program that runs .dmg-files) directly instead using open, you will be sure it will ork correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This will work (but only on OS X):

```
    try {
        String[] command = {"/usr/bin/hdiutil", "attach", "/Users/path/to/your.dmg"};
        String sendback = "";    
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        InputStream istr = proc.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istr));
        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sendback = sendback + str;
        }
        int resultCode = proc.waitFor();
        br.close();
        if (resultCode != 0) {
            throw new Exception("failed to open system profiler");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

DMGs are not executables, are apple diskimages

reference is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image)

thus you can't "run" it.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that is like asking how to run an ISO file through Java. You simply can't; it's a disk image.